# Non-calculator proof that $\pi^\pi -\pi \lt \frac{100}{3}$

Tags: inequality, computational-mathematics

I am looking for a few non-computational, non-calculator proof of the following inequality:

$$\pi^\pi -\pi \lt \frac{100}{3}$$

I can't really seem to come up with a proof because of that killer $\pi^\pi$ term.

Comment: What would constitue a "non-computational" proof? Especially considering that this looks like a purely numeric problem. (And the bound is pretty sharp.)

Comment: @mjl A non-computational proof is one that does not just approximate pi and calculate from that.

Comment: @John: It will need a pretty clever argument, since the lefthand side is about $33.320567$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That clever argument was what I was looking for, you know?

Comment: Can log be used

Comment: [The eternal question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19188)... :-$)$

Comment: @John: I realize that; I was just emphasizing the smallness of the gap, more for the benefit of anyone taking a casual look at the problem than for your benefit, since it makes it unlikely that a simple-minded approach will work. (I assumed that you were already well aware of it.)

Comment: I am going to ask this on MathOverflow. Anyone object?

Comment: It would help motivate solutions (and address the eternal question Lucian referred to) if you could say a little about *why* you want such a demonstration.  Where did this expression come from?  Is it just the coincidental result of some playing around with numbers?  (Nothing wrong with that, by the way.)  Or did it somehow arise from some other problem?  Such coincidences are neat to look at, but they are common enough that without something more behind them, one doesn't necessarily want to spend a lot of time on them...

Comment: Not really answering your question too much, but we also have $3.1416^{3.1416}-3.14<100/3$, which implies your result, so maybe you can focus on finding a non calculator way of showing this.

Comment: @JohnVine This is not for MathOverflow

Comment: "A non-computational proof is one that does not just approximate pi and calculate from that" That makes little sense to me. (And the currently upvoted -and nice- answer does precisely that).

Comment: Second leonbloy's comment.  MO is for research questions.

Comment: All, I realize now the purpose of MO. Sorry for my misunderstanding. The question is closed now so it really doesn't matter, but thank you all for your input

Comment: Your question could be interesting if you find it in solving another interesting problem. If it is not the case, then why not to prove $\pi^{\pi}+\pi<40$ without calculator instead of $\pi^{\pi}-\pi<\frac{100}{3}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inequality $x^x-x<100/3$ is true precisely when $0<x<3.14175798627357...$, so intuitively a solution to this problem must in some fashion make use of the fact that $$\pi<3.14175798627357\ldots.$$ The upper bound $\pi<22/7$ is insufficient for this, but the upper bound $355/113$ suffices. (The bound of $355/113$ dates to the fifth century CE, which I personally would be prepared to admit as "non-calculator".) One could therefore proceed as follows: since $x \mapsto x^x-x$ is increasing for $x>1$ (an easy calculus exercise), it is sufficient to show 
$$\left(\frac{355}{113}\right)^{\frac{355}{113}}-\frac{355}{113}<\frac{100}{3}$$
which is to say
$$\left(\frac{355}{113}\right)^{\frac{355}{113}}<\frac{12365}{339}$$
or
$$3\times 355^{\frac{355}{113}}<12365\times 113^{\frac{242}{113}}$$
or
$$3^{113}\times 355^{355}<12365^{113}\times 113^{242}.$$
It is not immediately obvious to me that this inequality cannot be obtained by hand within a broadly viable timeframe, but before attempting it I would probably start reading up on things like [Karatsuba multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm), and work out carefully beforehand how many pages I might need to fill with long multiplication calculations and endless repeated squaring. The gap between the two numbers is very small, one being about $1.7\times 10^{959}$ and the other around $1.8\times 10^{959}$. In any event, I hope that the sharpness of the inequality which needs to be proved illustrates the difficulty of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make the necessary tweaks. Are you sure about that 3413? I get 3423, which is fine.

Comment: Yes, you are right; I made an arithmetical error.  But I notice you have swapped $113$ for $133$ up there.  That's a more serious problem.

Comment: So I have. It did seem a bit too easy. Back to the blackboard for a bit then!

Comment: The fact that both numbers have the same number of digits (ETA: *when $113$ is properly substituted for $133$*) indicates that the razor *must* be sharper than a few powers of $2$.

Comment: For the benefit of voters: The current version of the answer (which references Karatsuba multiplication) requires $22$ multiplications (float-level precision should be enough) on the LHS and $21$ multiplications on the RHS.  That's tedious but doable.

Comment: A postscript: It seems possible to me that the arithmetical inequality above could be simplified by taking some very careful approximations: for example, if we replace $12365$ on the right with $12360$ then I think that the inequality is still true, but we can now eliminate a factor of $3^{113}\times 5^{113}$ from both sides. The bottom line, though, is that in order to follow this method "by hand" one will probably end up simply looking up what the calculator is doing behind the scenes, and then emulating the calculator on paper.

Comment: How do you calculate without calculator the bound 3.14175798627357...?

Comment: @Piquito: I used a calculator to find that out. I included that fact because I think it helps to illustrate how the problem works. It isn't actually actually used in the argument which follows.

Comment: If you have not used this bound, all it is right. Regards.